# IE fix for png not working

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

Does anyone know why the code below is not working? I would really like to use this method as opposed to any of the JavaScript method(s). I also tried the absolute path but no luck.

```
.test {
    width: 500px; /* Must Specify Width */
    height: 176px;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale, src='../images/test-bg.png');
}
```

Comment: Make sure the path is relative to the page it's displayed on, not the CSS file. So you tried src='/images/test-bg.png' ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `sizingMethod=scale` needs to be `sizingMethod="scale"`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've tried an absolute path, but have you tried the path from, not including, the domain?

So if the full path is "http://www.example.co.uk/images/test.png" you'd just use "/images/test.png"

This is how I have used it in the past

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/test-bg.png', sizingMethod=scale, enabled="true");`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other file references from within CSS files, the `filter` property's `src` attribute is relative to the URL in your browser. So, for your example code, assuming the images folder is at `http://www.yoursite.com/images` and your `src` used is `../images/test-bg.png`:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/                                -> Doesn't work
http://www.yoursite.com/some-page/                      -> Works
http://www.yoursite.com/some-page/another-level-deeper/ -> Doesn't work
```

The best way is to use a path relative to the root, like this:

`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/test-bg.png',sizingMethod='scale');`

If this isn't the problem, another possibility is that the size of the image might be too small. In the past, I've found that stretching a 1x1 pixel image can be buggy, and sometimes doesn't render properly. A workaround in this instance would be to use a bigger image (in excess of 5x5 pixels).